# redirect tag and $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php, html, redirect, http-referer

I have one index.html with redirect,  (javascript, meta or php its the same problem) to other server.

The html redirects to an external index.php where i have to print/echo -> parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST)

If I open the url with index.html it redirects and prints http_referer fine but if I open url directly, like http://portal-iso9001-2015.com/ (without index.html) it redirects but it does not print the http_referer.

Comment: The referrer comes into play when you are clicking through to a page from another page.  If you were to follow a link from Wikipedia to another site the referrer would indicate that you came from Wikipedia.  However if you just open up your browser and manually type in the address, then there is no referrer because you weren't referred.

Comment: in addition, its browser set so is unreliable.